# What does red color of block (not road) means on Google Maps?

Tags: google-maps

Like here

[image]

https://goo.gl/maps/sLBgA2MbgWKj32yk7

Note that roads are white, it is not traffic color.

Answer (score 1):

Areas or markers that are pink are public services open to the public. Train stations, hospitals, etc. It also includes underground pedestrian corridors.

In this case, it looks like there is a hospital there as indicated by the red H pin